# How to view the close reasons for failed close reviews?

Tags: support, review, close-reasons

**Relevant screenshot:** ([full page link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/close/77711))

> [image: review item screenshot]

This question's close review failed (3 x Leave Open, 1 x Close). I wish to know **how to view the specific close reason** which was given by the users who voted to close this question. The [timeline](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/94316/timeline) too does not specify that reason (it does give the reason when close review is successful though)

So, how do I view the close reasons for failed close reviews?

Comment: I don't think it's possible since voting is conceptually anonymous, just like you only know how many existing close votes on a post inside a review, but not the voters... or you only know who votes to close, but not the reason after the review is done (Talking about Heisenberg's Principle...)

Comment: @HTTPS But when the close review succeeds, the reasons associated with the name are shown anyway, aren't they? Besides, is there actually any anonymity at all, especially as the user's name is directly displayed?

Comment: Not always the case, [usually only the majority reason gets displayed, even if some users vote for different reasons, unless they vote for off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260145/multiple-close-reasons-no-longer-shown). The displayed names are only to show who are responsible for closing the question, irrelevant to the reason.